# Grails 3 JSON Views custom rendering one-to-many associations

Tags: json, view, grails-3.0

Okay I have tried everything I know to custom render a one-to-many association with JSON views and failed miserably.

Here's what part of my ticket domain looks like (All good here) ...

```
class TttTicket {

    String title
    String number
    String description
    TttUser assignee
    String priority
    String status
    TttUser creator


    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static mappedBy = [subscribers : 'none', creator:'none']

    static belongsTo = [project:TttProject, creator:TttUser]
    static hasMany = [subscribers: TttUser]

... blar blar 
}
```

Here's my associated gson rendering template...

```
import ttt_api_server.TttTicket

model {
    TttTicket tttTicket
}

json g.render(tttTicket, [excludes:['creator','subscribers','project']]){
    creator {
        id tttTicket.creator.id
        name tttTicket.creator.name
        email tttTicket.creator.email
    }

    project{
        id tttTicket.project.id
        name tttTicket.project.name
    }
}
```

... which is working nicely so far. I want to now restricted the output of the properties for each of the subscribers.

How do I rotate over these? For example...

```
import ttt_api_server.TttTicket

model {
    TttTicket tttTicket
}

json g.render(tttTicket, [excludes:['creator','subscribers','project']]){
    creator {
        id tttTicket.creator.id
        name tttTicket.creator.name
        email tttTicket.creator.email
    }
    subscibers g.render(){
        tttTicket.subscribers.each {sub ->
            return {
                name sub.name
            }
        }
    }
    project{
        id tttTicket.project.id
        name tttTicket.project.name
    }
}
```

This does not seem to be documented anywhere. I would like to controller the JSON out put of each subscriber at this level. Not at the domain level as I may need to change the property output depending on my JSON requirements.

Please help :-(

Comment: BTW - I have put in place an interim solution which includes only the properties I require on the subscriber class via it's gson but this is not the desired effect. I want to be able to retain all properties when doing a rest call directly to the subscribers, but restrict the properties when doing a rest call on tickets that have many subscribers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, when you do a REST call on ticket, you wanted the domain object that is inside the hasMany relationship to show a specified properties (in this case its subscribers). But when you call directly on the subscribers, you wanted all the properties.

You can create a map first and then render the objects based on the map created (have a look at [this](http://javasplitter.blogspot.my/2009/07/json-in-grails-with-nested-collections.html)).
In your case:

```
import ttt_api_server.TttTicket

model {
    TttTicket tttTicket
}

json g.render(tttTicket, [excludes:['creator','subscribers','project']]){
    creator {
        id tttTicket.creator.id
        name tttTicket.creator.name
        email tttTicket.creator.email
    }

    def s = tttTicket.subsribers.collect {
        [
            id: it.id,
            name: it.name
        ]
    }

    subscribers s //this part is doing the rendering

    project{
        id tttTicket.project.id
        name tttTicket.project.name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the way you want this object to be rendered whenever it's rendered as JSON, I suggest implementing `ObjectMarshaller<JSON>`:

```
class TttTicketMarshaller implements ObjectMarshaller<JSON> {

  @Override
  boolean supports(Object object) {
    return object instanceof TttTicket
  }

  @Override
  void marshalObject(Object object, JSON converter) throws ConverterException {
    TttTicket ticket = (TttTicket)object

    def jsonWriter = converter.writer
    jsonWriter.object()
    jsonWriter.key("title")
    jsonWriter.value(ticket.title)

    //other fields

    jsonWriter.key("creator")
    jsonWriter.object()
    jsonWriter.key("id")
    jsonWriter.value(ticket.creator.id)

    //other creator fields
    jsonWriter.endObject()
  }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure about the `object()` and `endObject()` functionality, but that appears to be the correct use.

Once you have this, register this in your `BootStrap.groovy`:

```
def init = { servletContext ->
  JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(new TttTicketMarshaller())
}
```

With all this in place, you can simply use

```
render myTicket as JSON
```

to return the JSON representation of the object as defined by your marshaller